# C++ WinForms parameters through System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms

I have to create new thread and send parameters to the threaded function, can't make it work though.
I was working according to this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx

Here is the thread creation (with the errors in the comments):

```
System::Threading::Thread^ T = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &Server::ClientHandler)); // ERROR: 'void Server::ClientHandler(System::Object ^,System::Object ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^)'
T->Start(ClientSocket); // ERROR: 'System::Threading::Thread::Start' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

Here is `ClientHandler` decleration:

```
void Server::ClientHandler(Object^ data, Object^ data1);
```

I tried it with only one parameter, and I had only the second error.

P.S, in `ClientHandler` function I have to convert the `Object^` parameters to `SOCKET*` and `SOCKADDR_IN*`, how it can be done?

My try:

```
SOCKET* _Sock = (SOCKET*)data;
SOCKADDR_IN* _ADDR = (SOCKADDR_IN*)data1;
```

I'm using visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that declaration for `Server::ClientHandler` is incorrect.

Should be:

```
void Server::ClientHandler(Object^ data)
{
    //Do stuff with data here..
}

System::Threading::Thread^ T = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &Server::ClientHandler));
T->Start("Pass Your Data Here");
```

Comment: so is it impossible to send 2 or more parameters?

Comment: Well it takes an Object. An object can be anything including an Array. You should be able to pass the second parameter still. The documentation says the thread takes a function pointer in the form of: `void ParameterizedThreadStart(Object^ obj);`

Comment: I made struct with the parameters; `struct ClientHandlerParameters Params;`

getting same error in `T->Start(Params);`.
I don't understand how can I convert the `struct ClientHandlerParameters` to Object.

Comment: Because a struct is not convertible to Object^.  A `value struct` is, so is a `ref class`.  You have to use a managed type.

Comment: Since I'm not experienced with `value struct` (and because the lack of information about it), I switched it to `ref class`. got it work.